# Convert image to black and white while preserving alpha channel

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I want to convert a png image that already has an Alpha channel (RGBA) to a black and white image.

I do it using the following category:

```
func convertToGrayScale() -> UIImage {
    let imageRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let width = self.size.width
    let height = self.size.height

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.None.rawValue)
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(width), Int(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, self.CGImage)
    let imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
    let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!)

    return newImage
}
```

But when I change the `CGImageAlphaInfo` to anything other than `None`, my `imageRef` returns nil, thus fore crashing the app.

Is there a way, or am I trying something that's not possible?

Comment: Please try CoreImage Filter
You can search core image filter reference for iOS in apple docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed it using [CoreImage filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPhotoEffectMono) as Yi.Zhang suggested :)

```
func convertToGrayScale() -> UIImage {
    let filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")!
    filter.setDefaults()
    filter.setValue(CoreImage.CIImage(image: self)!, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    return UIImage(CGImage: CIContext(options:nil).createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, fromRect: filter.outputImage!.extent))
}
```

(Swift 2.0)